# Authorize Php Simple Checkout Form

Tags: php, authorize.net

I want to implement a simple checkout with php using Authorize.net SDk. I got really confused with all the API's available:

Right now I'm using AIM api :

```
$sale = new AuthorizeNetAIM;
    $sale->setFields(
        array(
            // aici
            'amount'     => $total_price,
            'card_num'   => $data['CreditCardNumber'],
            'exp_date'   => $data['ExpirationDate'],
            'tax'        => $tax,

            // Billing Information
            'zip'     => $data['Zip'],
            'country' => $data['Country'],
            'address' => $data['Address'],

            // Shipping Information
            'ship_to_first_name' => $data['CardHolder'],
            'ship_to_address'    => $data['Address'],
            'ship_to_city'       => $data['City'],
            'ship_to_company'    => 'No Comapny',
            'ship_to_country'    => $data['Country'],
            'ship_to_zip'        => $data['Zip']
      )
    );
```

AIM used to work on my development server, but now it returns an error, it cannot connect to Authorize.

Comment: Does your server support TLS 1.2?

Comment: Fixed it but adding SSL ignore on the curl requests, the live website will have SSL, I will remove them afterwards :)

Comment: You should make that an answer and accept it so future users who have the same issue can find the solution. It also prevents the system from periodically bumping this question.

Answer (score 0):

They have [official PHP SDK](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php)

get **MerchantAuthenticationType**

```
$merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
$merchantAuthentication->setName("YOURLOGIN");
$merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey("YOURKEY");
```

get **SubscriptionList**

```
$sorting = new net\authorize\api\contract\v1\ARBGetSubscriptionListSortingType();
$sorting->setOrderBy('firstName');
$sorting->setOrderDescending(false);
```

Find more samples here : https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php